# Is there a cold/hot signal in swift Combine（likes SignalProducers /Signals in ReactiveCocoa）?

Tags: ios, swift, combine, reactive-swift

I recently started using swift's [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine) (I've used ReactiveCocoa before), I'm wondering if there is a concept of cold and hot signals also in Combine?  Dose `Publisher` is equal to cold signals(SignalProducers), and No hot signal in Combine? Thanks~

Comment: "Dose Publisher is equal to cold signals(SignalProducers), and No hot signal in Combine" No. In fact, most publishers in Combine are hot. Messages from a notification center, a Published property, etc. can arrive at any time. Good discussion at https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/twenty-two-short-tests-of-combine-part-2.html Keep in mind that Combine uses _backpressure_ which rather changes the equation.

Comment: @matt thanks for comment! For a Publisher, depends on how it was created, It could be a hot signal or cold signal, For example when using Subject or NotificationCenter's Publisher, it would be a hot signal,  when using Future or Just, It would be a cold signal, Is this correct?

Comment: That's probably right, although I prefer to think of these as simply persistent publishers vs. "one-shot" publishers. :)

Answer (score 2):

A Publisher could be either cold or hot depending on what is backing it. By default though, publishers are cold with specific operators designed to heat them up.

Unlike in ReactiveCocoa, in Combine both hot and cold publishers use the same type.

Answer (score 2):

In combine the matter is a little bit more intricate than mere being hot or cold. By default the Apple uses mechanism called backpressure which simply is what we've known as cold flow in Kotlin and other reactive programming. In Swift we have hot publishers like: NotificationCenter.Publisher, and the @Published wrapper in SwiftUI. By default, most publishers in Combine are inherently cold, however there are operators to change a publisher to a hot publisher such as share operator.

```
   let coldPublisher = Just("Hello, World!")
   let hotPublisher = coldPublisher.share()
```

The same can be achieved via using Subject publishers too.

```
 let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
 let hotPublisher = subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
 // Now you can emit values using `subject.send("Hello")`
```

you can also create your own custom publisher too.

```
 struct MyHotPublisher: Publisher {
         typealias Output = String
         typealias Failure = Never

         func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber { 
          // Implement your custom logic here 
         // Emit values to the subscriber 
         }
  }
```